# ListFragment is empty after navigating back

Tags: android, android-fragments

Okay, I know there is a lot of discussion according to this topic, but I couldn't find any answer.

My problem is the following: 
I have an `Activity` with `NavigationDrawer`, so the `Fragments` are added from code. The first fragment is a `ListFragment`, witch reads data from an SQLite DB stored in the SD card. The data loading is kind of slow, because I load the nearest n place based on location. So I don't want to load the list every time.

Now, if the user clicks an item, a second `Activity` shows the details. The first strange stuff is the first activity is destroyed almost every time a leave it, witch is awful, but still I could save the state.

The discussions that I rad so far indicated that the `Activity` should retain the last displayed `Activity`, and it kind of does, because if I change the content of the first activity from the Drawer before navigation the correct `Fragment` is created.

The problem is that even if the `ListFragment` is being re-used its contents will be missing (since I create a new `View` in the `onCreateView()` because of custom layout). I guess I should use the `Bundle` provided as a parameter in `onCreateView()`, but I just couldn't figure it out.

So summed up: what is the proper way of saving the items of a `ListFragment`, even if its parent activity is destroyed?

Comment: make the list `static` maybe?

Comment: actually, parent activity is not destroyed when you call another activity from it. you may go back to it and continue from where you left. at least it is not supposed to be destroyed

Comment: Yeah, static list would work, but feels hackish. And the Activity being destroyed is normal afaik, since Android can destroy any Activity not on foreground for memory for example. Now I know that I should save the state, but a couldn't because even if the same Fragment is used when recreating the Activity, it's fields including the View and Adapter are not retained.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had a developer option turned on that killed all Activities that I navigate from. I didn't know that because I use my phone in Hungarian (guess it'll change from now), and for some reason they felt like they had to translate the word "Activity", making the whole option description not understandable. Sorry about that, now my first Activity is kept in the memory, so the whole issue is not present...